# Exclude module dependencies in jboss AS 7 (EAP 6) when using MANIFEST.MF

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I know I can make it using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, but Is it doable using `MANIFEST.MF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code, the method: `o.j.a.s.d.m.ModuleSpecification.addExclusion` is only called by `o.j.a.s.d.m.d.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser`, and the `o.j.a.s.d.m.ManifestDependencyProcessor`only add modules (no exclusions).

So, the Answer AFAIK is **NO**, we cannot use `MANIFEST.MF` to define module exculsions.

Comment: Yes, You need to use

Comment: Yes, You need to use jboss-deployment-structure.xml.. To exclude subsystem within a module, you will will want to exclude the entire module and then add back in each of the subsystems that make the module minus the subsystem that needs to be excluded.

Comment: For e.g. exclude javax.ws.rs.api from javaee.api module:
~~~
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
 
    <exclusions>
      <module name="javaee.api"/>
    </exclusions>
<dependencies>
....
</dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
~~~